# .NET Third Part Active Directory APIs?

Tags: .net, active-directory

Was wondering if anyone had any recommendations on a .NET (preferebly 3.5) Active Directory API wrapper around the .NET libraries?

Essentially, I'm looking for a class library that could be dropped into a project or even exposed in larger part of a company-wide framework that takes a lot of the hassle of writing your own.

Also, ideally using a third part assembly would take a great deal of the maintenance work out.

Comment: did you ever find one? the .NET APIs are awful, doing my head in

Answer (score 1):

There is a .NET lib called

```
System.DirectoryServices
```

It's installed with the .net framework. It's not included by default in a project.
Just do "add reference". then the .NET tab then System.DirectoryServices.

Comment: I'm aware of the .NET libraries. I was looking for recommendations on wrappers around these .Net libraries...

Answer (score 1):

Just to note, Active Directory is an LDAP implementation. In addition to System.DirectoryServices, already mentioned.  Novel developed an LDAP provider, that should work fine with AD.   here's some more info on [Novell.Directory.Ldap](http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/Ldapcsharp)

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it yet, but am looking for the same thing and ran across this site. Seem like it has all the features needed to easily do the common tasks needed in an enterprise application.

http://dotnetactivedirectory.com/